# jQuery Mobile - How to change the css classes to be applied when i use a data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am building a mobile app with jQuery Mobile. I am trying to apply my own design to it, i was going good so far, but i came up with a problem.

I am trying to build as much clean ui as i can, so i am trying to eliminate shadows, gradients etc. But, when i put `data-role="listview"` to a `<div>` element, it automatically puts some css classes to it, and one of them is ui-shadow, which i don't want to use it for my listviews.

So far, i thought about changing the javascript code of jquery mobile, but i believe it is not the best practice.

It would be awesome if I can get your ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use the JQM themes at all, If you want you can use just the [structure](http://jquerymobile.com/download/) css file without a theme.

Comment: Yeah i know but, what i meant is that, it's js file puts those css classes to it. I am wondering how can i change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practice that we have taken up with JQM and its respective CSS is that we do not touch those files since they can be updated when a new version comes out. We load our own custom JS and css files after the JQM ones respectively. In our own files, we specify the specific, customized items that we want to change that cannot simply be taken care of by attributes in HTML tags. We just redefine the class or function in it's respective place. I hope that helps and keeps you moving forward without actually having to touch JQM files.

Comment: Yeah, after some messing aroud, we solved the problem like you did. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify whether or not you want shadows (and other things) on widgets via `data-*` attributes.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-shadow="false">
    ...
</ul>
```

After creating a JSFiddle test I realized that jQuery Mobile does not allow you to remove shadows from inset list-view widets via an option, you can however do this with most widgets, like a button.Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4VXfb/

```
<a data-role="button" data-shadow="false" href="#">I'm a button without shadows.</a>
```

See documentation for a jQuery Mobile widget's options here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html

Comment: Thanks for those you said. But, i guess, i only have the css editing choice for my inline list.

Comment: @UmutŞirin Did you see the note about listviews?